# Sending file objects using AppleScript + bash

Tags: bash, applescript, imessage

I'm hoping to programmatically send files via `imessage`, yet cannot figure out how to send a file object via the API.

This script send a message to a specified user with the file path:

```
imessage() {
    file="$PWD/$2";
    osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to send '\"$file\"' to buddy '\"$1\"';
}
```

How can I send the actual file? A pointer to the docs for this would also be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't automate anything you don't know how to do yourself. You'll have to figure out how to use AppleScript to send a file before you can have Bash ask AppleScript to send a file.

Comment: BTW, note that the pattern given in the code in the question is prone to injection attacks -- someone who controls the filenames can run arbitrary programs on your machine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Noted, this is for personal use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the easiest way to do this is to create an AppleScript file and call this via bash as demonstrated here https://gist.github.com/homam/0119797f5870d046a362.

AppleScript - sendmessage.scpt

```
on run argv
    set filename to item 1 of argv
    set buddyName to item 2 of argv
    set attach to POSIX file filename
    tell application "Messages" to send attach to buddy buddyName
end run
```

Bash script

```
imessage() {
    osascript sendmessage.scpt "$PWD/$2" "$1";
}
```